# Dynamic multiple search filter in Multidimensional Array php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

First of all credits to the maker of the array search function. What I need is to make it filter multiple keys in array. The current function was only limited to search 1 key and value per use.

```
$arr = array(0 => array(id=>1,name=>"cat 1"),
         1 => array(id=>2,name=>"cat 2"),
         2 => array(id=>3,name=>"cat 1")
);
```

And below is the function(Credits to owner):

```
function search($array, $key, $value)
{
    $results = array();
    search_r($array, $key, $value, $results);
    return $results;
}

function search_r($array, $key, $value, &$results)
{
   if (!is_array($array)) {
      return;
}

if (isset($array[$key]) && $array[$key] == $value) {
    $results[] = $array;
}

foreach ($array as $subarray) {
    search_r($subarray, $key, $value, $results);
  }
}
```

If I use search($arr, 'name', 'cat 1') it will return:

```
array(0 => array(id=>1,name=>"cat 1"),
  1 => array(id=>3,name=>"cat 1")
);
```

But if I want it to filter by 'name' => 'cat 1' and 'id' => 1, it will only return:

```
array(0 => array(id=>1,name=>"cat 1")
);
```

But I need the function in accept dynamic filter parameter for I will use it over different multidimensional arrays. Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Edit:

What I have tried so far

```
public function search($array, $search)
{
    $results = array();
    foreach($search as $key => $value){
        $condition[] = 'isset($subarray["'.$key.'"]) && $subarray["'.$key.'"] == "'.$value.'"';
    }

    $filter = implode($condition, ' && ');

    foreach($array as $subarray){
        if ($filter) {
            $results[] = $subarray;
      }
    }

    return $results;
}
```

But I can't run $filter as php code. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Not the most optimized solution, but you can use [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) in combination with [`array_intersect_assoc`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-assoc.php):

```
function search(array $array, array $search)
{
    return array_filter($array, function ($item) use ($search) {
        return array_intersect_assoc($search, $item) === $search;
    });
}
```

Here is [working demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c9554d3e930e20567d30dbab27961603a169cf33).