# php multidimensional array count dynamically

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, filter, count

I have two arrays $users and $find. I need count how many matches in $users if $find array would be changed.

```
$users = array(
    [
        'name' => 'Jim',
        'sname' => 'Carrey'
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'Michael',
        'sname' => 'Douglas'
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'Michael',
        'sname' => 'Jackson'
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'Michael',
        'sname' => 'Jordan'
    ]
);
```

Find array changed dynamically. It may be:

```
$find = array (
    'name' => array('Michael'),
    'sname' => array('Douglas', 'Jordan')
);
```

OR:

```
$find = array (
    'sname' => array('Carrey', 'Jordan')
);
```

I'm looking for a one-size-fits-all solution for for any values in $find array.
Thanks!

I can count if I have static keys and values in $find array:

```
$result = array_filter($users, function($user) {
    return in_array($user['name'], ['Michael', 'Jim']) && in_array($user['sname'], ['Douglas', 'Jordan', 'Carrey']);
});
$count = count($result);
print_r($result);
```

But I don't understand how count if it should be dynamic keys and values in $find array.

Comment: Related: [Filter array of associative arrays with a dynamic associative array where all elements must be matched](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72154046/2943403) and [Dynamic multiple search filter in Multidimensional Array php](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46311755/2943403) and [How to filter an array based on multiple selected values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75275820/2943403)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to deal with an unknown number of items in `$find`, then you will need to loop over them. The `use` keyword helps to "inject" $find into your callback function. In your loop, you can return false, if the in_array check for the current find item results in false, otherwise you return true after the loop.

```
$result = array_filter($users, function($user) use ($find) {
    foreach($find as $col => $values) {
        if(!in_array($user[$col], $values)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
});
```